# Convert Mysql query to Laravel elequent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I trying to convert MySQL query to Laravel eloquent, but not getting the right output.

MySQL query -

```
Select contents.con_type, contents.operation, contents.ecu, contents.ecu_sub, COUNT(*)
    from contents 
    group by operation, con_type, ecu, ecu_sub 
    order by operation asc, con_type asc
```

MySQL query to Laravel elequent -

```
$content = Content::query();
if ($request->input('total') == '1') {
$content = $content->select('con_type', 'operation', 'ecu', 'ecu_sub')
                   ->groupBy('operation', 'con_type', 'ecu', 'ecu_sub')
                   ->orderBy('operation', 'asc')
                   ->orderBy('con_type', 'asc')
                   ->get()->count();
}
```

The output I trying to get:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` must be specified in output list with another fields. Use ```$content->select(DB::raw('contents.con_type, contents.operation, contents.ecu, contents.ecu_sub,count(*) as `count`')```. `...->get()->count();` counts the amount of records in output, is it?

Comment: Yes, it only counts all the records, but not how many times that row repeats in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```
$content = Content::query();
if ($request->input('total') == '1') {
$content = $content->select(DB::raw('con_type, operation, ecu, ecu_sub, count(*) as `count`')
                   ->groupBy('operation', 'con_type', 'ecu', 'ecu_sub')
                   ->orderBy('operation', 'asc')
                   ->orderBy('con_type', 'asc')
                   ->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
Maybe there is a way how to achieve the same output, but using eloquent, not raw query?

Comment: @DomantasŠlaičiūnas I do not see another variant in [Laravel: Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions). [#Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates) gives only the code for retrieving the data over all output dataset.